# SpeechRecognition available in Python 3.9+

Tags: python, speech-recognition, python-3.9

In PYPI SpeechRecognition, it states that the Package is only supported up to Python version 3.6

I have successfully got it working in Python 3.6. in the past.  But now upgraded to Python3.9.1.  SpeechRecognition does not work as it is not supported.

Does anyone know a good workaround (in Python) to handle SpeechRecognition that returns the **text** not an audio file?

Many thanks!!

Comment: This project does not seem to be actively supported, so you might be out of luck here. Maybe one of these versions can help you: https://pypi.org/project/speech-recognition-python/3.9.9/#history ?

Answer (score 1):

Both Google and AWS will work, from my experience, Google is faster and more accurate but does not work as well with compressed file types, so you'd best go with a wav. If these solutions aren't applicable, you always can use a virtual environment with an older version of python.

I also read through their documentation and it said that versions 3.3+ are all supported, so maybe updating the library will fix your issue.

(for the Google and AWS transcription services I have created some handy toolkits which would make the process much easier)

Hope this helped!